# ModernHttpClient Not Compartible with Web Appication Project

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

i am currently using Restclient to send request via web api for xamarin, it works well with windows and ios but i doesnt work for andriod , i searched and found a nuget package that will help, called ModernHttpClient,so it changes my code from `var httpclient = new HttpClient();` to `var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());` but when i install it for the web application i keep getting an error stating the package is not compatible with the project. but it installs ok in android,ios and windows. i tried uninstalling it from the web application but i doesnt work in the code unless it appears in all the project.

so i  want to find the reason why the package is not compatible with the web appication or a solution to the Restclient request not working on android .

Comment: is your Web project making its own HTTP requests, or just responding to requests from clients?  If it's the latter then there is no reason that it should need to have the ModernHttp package installed.

Comment: its making HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [product page for modernhttpclient on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/) doesn't list any dependencies, but changing the domain name of the URL to use [fuget.org instead of nuget.org](https://www.fuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/) lists monoandroid, monotouch, portable-net45+winrt45+wp8+wpa81, and xamarin.ios10. Therefore, these are the target frameworks that the package supports.

Another way to check what TFMs (target framework monikers) a package supports is to find/download the nupkg and then open it as a zip file, or use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/p/nuget-package-explorer/9wzdncrdmdm3) to look for subfolders under `lib/`.

You didn't say what target framework your web app is using, but this is where things start getting very complicated and I don't understand it very well. .NET Framework TFMs are compatible with other .NET Framework TFMs of lower versions. Similarly .NET Core TFMs are compatiable with other .NET Core TFMs of lower versions. [.NET Standard is a whole other complication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). NuGet also supports fallback or alternate TFM compatibility, to allow .NET Core apps to use libraries targetting .NET Framework, but it's a best guess and might fail at runtime (maybe it's even possible to fail to compile, I'm not sure, but restore will succeed with a warning). Given you're not getting the warning, but instead an error, it suggests to me that portable-net45 is not compatible with net45 and therefore probably isn't compatible with whatever target framework you're using with your web app (unless your web app is targetting net40 or earlier).

Having said all that, when I was looking at the package to see which frameworks it targets, I saw that the whole point of the package is to use the platform native HTTP stack, instead of Xamerin's HTTP stack on the mobile platforms. Your web app isn't running on a mobile platform, it's running on either .NET Core or .NET Framework, so you shouldn't need the package. I suggest you use `#if`, `#else` and `#endif` to use NativeMessageHandler only on Android and IOS, and then use the default HTTPClient constructor (or use HttpMessageHandler) on other platforms.

Comment: i used the `#if`,`#else` and `#endif` for platform specific and it works Thank you, so youve solved the problem. but if you can help me , the request still isnt working on android

Comment: Please open a new question and give more details about what service you're trying to call, what error you're getting, does it fail in the android emulator or only real devices, have you tried calling a web service you control so that you can check the logs to check the request is sent as expected, etc. Please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. Providing a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is particularly helpful to people trying to answer.